# ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 22]

Tags: pip

Hi im trying to install voevent-parse via pip and run into the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError. Traceback (most recent call last):   File "c:\users\timo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 171, in _merge_into_criterion
    crit = self.state.criteria[name] KeyError: 'voevent-parse'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\timo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 316, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "c:\users\timo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\resolver.py", line 121, in resolve
    self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "c:\users\timo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 453, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "c:\users\timo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 318, in resolve
    name, crit = self._merge_into_criterion(r, parent=None)
  File "c:\users\timo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 173, in _merge_into_criterion
    crit = Criterion.from_requirement(self._p, requirement, parent)
  File "c:\users\timo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 82, in from_requirement
    if not cands:
  File "c:\users\timo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\structs.py", line 124, in __bool__
    return bool(self._sequence)
  File "c:\users\timo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 99, in __bool__
    return any(self)
  File "c:\users\timo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\factory.py", line 237, in iter_index_candidates
    candidate = self._make_candidate_from_link(
  File "c:\users\timo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\factory.py", line 165, in _make_candidate_from_link
    self._link_candidate_cache[link] = LinkCandidate(
  File "c:\users\timo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 300, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "c:\users\timo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 144, in __init__
    self.dist = self._prepare()
  File "c:\users\timo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 226, in _prepare
    dist = self._prepare_distribution()
  File "c:\users\timo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 311, in _prepare_distribution
    return self._factory.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(
  File "c:\users\timo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 457, in prepare_linked_requirement
    return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
  File "c:\users\timo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 480, in _prepare_linked_requirement
    local_file = unpack_url(
  File "c:\users\timo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 240, in unpack_url
    unpack_file(file.path, location, file.content_type)
  File "c:\users\timo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\unpacking.py", line 266, in unpack_file
    untar_file(filename, location)
  File "c:\users\timo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\unpacking.py", line 230, in untar_file
    with open(path, 'wb') as destfp:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\Timo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-wpb7xknq\\voevent-parse_090e9cbdcae64f31a771cb0698293f1a\\src/voeventparse/fixtures/MOA_Lensing_Event_2015-07-10T14:50:54.00.xml'
Removed build tracker: 'C:\\Users\\Timo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-tracker-cmjrk9m4'
```

Im using the latest Windows 10 version and latest pip version

Answer (score 0):

Please consider running your command line in administrator